# Data is not displayed in view Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I am trying to display data from database to detail.blade.php, but no data is displayed in the view.

Here is the detail.blade.php view:

```
 <h6 class="card-title">Order No. {{ $order->order_number }}</h6>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="date">Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="order_date" value="{{ $order->order_date}}" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="handle">Handle by</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="." readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="status">Status</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="status" value="{{ $order->status}}" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subtotal">Subtotal</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="billing_subtotal" value="{{ $order->billing_subtotal}}" readonly>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

OrderMenuController:

```
 public function show(Order $order)
{
    $data = DB::table('order_menu')
        ->join('menus', 'menus.id', '=', 'order_menu.menu_id')
        ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_menu.order_id')
        ->select('orders.*', 'menus.name', 'order_menu.quantity')
        ->where('orders.id', $order->id)
        ->get();

    return view('admin.order.detail')->with([
        'order' => $order,
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

And for the route:

```
 Route::namespace("App\Http\Controllers\Admin")->prefix("admin")->name("admin.")->middleware('can:adminpage')->group(function () {
 Route::resource("/ordermenu", OrderMenuController::class);
 });
```

Tried dd($order) in the controller, and this is what comes up:

[image]

How to solve this? thank you

Comment: have you tried `@dd($order)` 
and if so, what comes up?

Comment: @omaresmaeel I've edited my question, when I try dd($order) that is what comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `dd()` shows that you don't have any attributes for the order instance, so it makes sense that you got any result back

Try To change the resource route into orders it might work for you